# Unable to cut-paste files to a destination folder in java using spring batch multithreading

Tags: multithreading, file, synchronization, spring-batch

I'm using file.renameTo(destination) to move files from source to dest folder in java using multithreading. Though I get no error, not all files are being cut-pasted. I also tried to synchronize the method that does this opertation, but in vain. I dont want to move files together.

The above step is used in conjunction with spring batch where I want to move files to different folders based on success or failure of an operation.

Comment: Adding the code for what you're trying to accomplish would help us provide insight.

Comment: Here is the code ---
`File src = new File("C:/xml/test.xml");
`File logDir = new File("C:/success/");

`if (logDir.exists() == false)
      `logDir.mkdirs();
   
`File dest = new File(logDir, "test.xml");

`//cut-paste a given file from src to dest dir.
`if(!dest.exists())
 `src.renameTo(dest);

I'm using multithreading and multiprocessing using spring batch, where each thread is assigned multiple files 
and it is these individual files that are to be moved to separate dir upon success or failure of the current execution.

Comment: Alternatively, I adopted to first copy files to dest dir and then perform delete operation.

`File src = new File("abs path of the src file");
`File dest = new File("dest path");

`FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(src, dest);
`src.deleteOnExit();